# Не работает проброска портов

Tags: веб-программирование, router, port

8080 порт в роутере был проброшен для работы apache tomcat, но при обращении к IP-роутера:8080 перенаправление не происходит. Как решить такую проблему?
[image: forwarding]

[image: testing]

Answer (score 1):

Вы обращаетесь к tomcat из своей локальной сети, а проброс портов делается для wan интерфейса, т.е. для доступа "извне". Еще для проброса портов (в зависимости от модели роутера) иногда приходиться в файерволе разрешать подключение к порту который надо пробрасывать. В вашем случае, может протребоваться разрешить доступ к wan интерфейсу (интернет) порт 8080
Для проверки доступа можно воспользоваться [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)